# How to create the circle videoview in android studio

Tags: android

I've tried to create the circle videoview in android studio like in the below image:

[image: the image I want to get]

But I got this:

[image: the image I got]

This is my layout_xml codechip:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
android:weightSum="1">

<VideoView
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="359dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/call_screen"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_videoview"
    android:layout_weight="0.54" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/drop"
        android:id="@+id/drop_call_btn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:text="OPEN"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/open_call_btn"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mute"
        android:id="@+id/mute_call_btn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

circle_videoview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"

    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >

   <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

   <stroke
       android:width="2dp"
       android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use an exact size for the video. Perhaps a percent of the screen would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not touching VideoView itself: i think drawable in background won't affect video stream.

You can put videoview after some imageview, in which you can set your interface image(with transparent circle in center) or with your shape drawable.

Comment: I am new on android studio